# How to change soap context's mode in Gsoap when deploying a service using mod_gsoap?

Tags: c++, apache, gsoap

So I am deploying a web service developed using gsoap using mod_gsoap. I wanted to set `SOAP_IO_KEEPALIVE` and `SOAP_IO_CHUNK` modes of the soap context object to accept chunked requests. How do I achieve this?
Or is there any other way to accept chunked requests? Right now the server responds as soon as it receives the first chunk without waiting for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.genivia.com/doc/apache/html/index.html#plugins) says:

> **Warning**
>
> Do not use any of the SOAP_IO flags to initialize or set the
>   context, such as `SOAP_IO_KEEPALIVE` and `SOAP_IO_CHUNK`.

The Apache server controls the connection settings and HTTP payload parameters to send and receive HTTP requests. Data is received with [`ap_get_client_block`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/group__APACHE__CORE__PROTO.html), which de-chunks the content when chunked.

Comment: Right now it looks like httpd is not dechunking the request. How do I configure it to do so?